# what trustlevel must I use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am launching my first website. I have published it and I am getting this error.

```
 The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
```

What trustlevel should I use now the site is online?

```
<system.web>
<securityPolicy>
<trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

are there any other web.config settings I must be aware of now I am putting the site online? Like changing the connectionstring?

Comment: You might be specifying full trust, but the hosting company might not be allowing that.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta is specifying full trust harmful to my security?

Comment: Depending what trustlevel you are using you will not have permission to do some tasks, for sample, reflection and compoenents that uses reflection as nHibernate, it needs full trust level. Look iy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @FelipeOriani How do I know what trustlevel my host uses? And how do I set the application to use that trustlevel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

inside `<system.web>`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your host provider, you may need to take out the compilers as well.

In my experience with GoDaddy I had to comment out my compilers and put trust level="Full".

Set your custom errors to On or RemoteOnly so end users do not see any error messages a.k.a "the yellow screen of death".

```
<system.web>
      <trust level="Full" />
      <customErrors mode="On" />
      ..... other settings in system.web ...
</system.web>

<system.codedom>
     <compilers>
       <!-- <compiler language="..." /> -->
       <!-- <compiler language="..." /> -->
     </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```